# Reordering rows in a bar chart using geom_col

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have the following simple code for generating a bar chart using the geom_col command in ggplot2:

```
plt <- ggplot(data) +
        geom_col(aes(Participations,Country), fill = BLUE, width = 0.6)
```

My data is a simple dataframe with two variables, `Countries` and `Participations`, where each country corresponds to a number. The result I get sorts the rows based on the alphabetical order of the countries. How can I modify this to reorder the bar chart based on the number of participations of each country?

I've tried using the `reorder()` function, but I'm not sure about the correct syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct syntax of `reorder` (in the context of `ggplot2`) is `(aes(x = reorder(x, -y), y = y)` or `(aes(x = reorder(x, y), y = y)`, depending if you want to start with the highest or lowest value of `y`.

Also make sure `fill = "blue"`, unless `BLUE` is another specified vector that corresponds to a real color.

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(123)

Country <- c("USA", "UK", "ESP", "FR", "ITA", "BRA", "JAP", "CHN", "ZAF", "DEU")
Participations <- sample(1:10, size = 10, replace = TRUE)
data <- data.frame(Country, Participations)

ggplot(data) + 
  geom_col(aes(x = reorder(Country, -Participations),
               y = Participations), fill = "blue", width = 0.6) +
  xlab("Country")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that's really helpful. How can I make the countries appearing on the Y axis though, starting with the highest participation on top? Something like this: https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/documents/4187653/9422887/Household_consumption_expenditure+_food_2017.png

Comment: You can add `+ coord_flip()` at the end of your plot. Just note that you'll need to fix any `xlab("name")` or `ylab("name")` arguments appropriately.